# Facebook Login CallbackManager FacebookCallback called onCancel() every time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am implementing login via facebook and get user email id using SDK 4.1.0 as shown in [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#overview) but problem occurring is that every time after onActivityResult when registerCallback is called then instead of onSuccess onCancel is called.

```
package com.dexterous.hellologin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    // If using in a fragment
    //   loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization
    // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.e("TAG", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.e("TAG", "onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.e("TAG", "error");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("TAG", "onActivityResult");
   }
}
```

every time i am getting output

**onActivityResult**

**onCancel**

neither i am getting that facebook login screen containing buttons cancel and login.

after uninstall  facebook app from mobile error changed to **Invalid App ID**

and this is stacktrace

> 06-04 10:55:16.631  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/WebViewFactory﹕ Loading com.google.android.webview version 42.0.2311.138 (code 2311138)
>   06-04 10:55:16.706  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/LibraryLoader﹕ Time to load native libraries: 4 ms (timestamps 8772-8776)
>   06-04 10:55:16.706  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
>   06-04 10:55:16.717  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
>   06-04 10:55:16.816  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {28a6fbd9}
>   06-04 10:55:16.816  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
>   06-04 10:55:16.819  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
>   06-04 10:55:16.834  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
>   06-04 10:55:16.838  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
>   06-04 10:55:16.841  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
>   06-04 10:55:16.869  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(286)] locale_file_path.empty()
>   06-04 10:55:16.870  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=63 off=46992 len=3337
>   06-04 10:55:16.871  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(76)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:64 off:7953032 len:1161174
>   06-04 10:55:17.024  19864-19953/com.dexterous.hellologin W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(150)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
>   06-04 10:55:17.047  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
>   06-04 10:55:17.060  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
>   06-04 10:55:24.893  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin W/BindingManager﹕ Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 19864
>   06-04 10:55:26.140  19864-20020/com.dexterous.hellologin E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Invalid texture format! Returning error!
>   06-04 10:55:26.140  19864-20020/com.dexterous.hellologin E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
>   06-04 10:55:26.198  19864-19912/com.dexterous.hellologin E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Invalid texture format! Returning error!
>   06-04 10:55:26.198  19864-19912/com.dexterous.hellologin E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
>   06-04 10:58:32.287  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin E/TAG﹕ onCancel
>   06-04 10:58:32.287  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin E/TAG﹕ onActivityResult
>   06-04 10:59:25.498  19864-19864/com.dexterous.hellologin I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16056(1325KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/16MB, paused 856us total 79.028ms

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.dexterous.hellologin.MainActivity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="1437829111203883" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show your androidmainfest file

Comment: @Singhak added androidmainfest

Comment: you can do one thing that keep you app id in string.xml

Comment: <string name="app_id">1437829111203883 </string>

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

Comment: @Singhak what is difference between putting key in string.xml or direct in menifest as it will be replacing by string.xml

Comment: i donot knw but when i write directly it giving me error

Comment: what happen you get something

Comment: @Singhak yes problem is solved by replacing app id in Stirng.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Problem is here that you are using Facebook APPId directly and You should use Like this

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

> In sting xml

```
<string name="app_id">1437829111203883 </string>
```

Comment: In my case i had used a different launcher activity which i changed later but missed changing in Facebook App details which caused the error

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that the onCancel() is still called because user is already logged on.
try calling
`LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()`
before initiating your login sequence

Answer (score 0):

try giving permission to facebook line this:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Mainactivity2.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```